# Google Pixel 4a mic issue - mic won't work when earphones are inserted into headphone jack

Tags: headphones, hardware, headphone-jack

When I am on a call, the mic on my Google Pixel 4a works perfectly. When I insert earphones into the headphone jack during a call, the mic suddenly stops working and the other person can't hear me anymore. When I remove the earphones, they can hear me again. What could be causing this?

All I want is to be able to hear the person through my earphones and for them to hear me.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this behaviour is that your phone detects that you plugged in an audio device, and then tries to use that one over all audio devices it has built into. So instead of using the built in microphone it wants to use the one that is usually built into the volume buttons on your headphone cable. If there is none, than the phone should use the default one, but maybe it just doesn't recognise that there is no external microphone attached.

Comment: I think this is probably what is causing the issue, but I am answering the questions myself as I found the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I tried good quality earphones and headphones and the issue disappeared. It seems to be a compatibility issue with the earphones I was using. As DarkDiamond suggested, perhaps they were being mistakenly recognized as a microphone.

Anyway, if anyone experiences this issue, simply try a different pair of earphones/headphones.